# android opencv Utils.BitmapToMap runtime exception help?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to convert a JPEG that is in a bitmap to a mat. I know that the Utils method only supports images in RGB888 format so I take force my camera to be in JPEG format, take the picture, decode it and the convert it to RGB 888 format and then call the utils method to get a mat from it. Here is the basic code:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mData, 0, mData.length);
double scale = 0.5; // Make the image smaller incase I was running out of memeory.
imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, (int) (imageBitmap.getWidth() * scale),
                    (int) (imageBitmap.getHeight() * scale), false);

imageBitmap = PNGtoRGB888(imageBitmap);
Mat m = Utils.bitmapToMat(imageBitmap); // I get a runtime exception
```

Here is the PNGtoRGB888 method:

```
private Bitmap PNGtoRGB888(Bitmap _img)
    {
        int numPixels = _img.getWidth() * _img.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[numPixels];

        // Get Bitmap's pixels. Each int is the color values for one pixel.
        _img.getPixels(pixels, 0, _img.getWidth(), 0, 0, _img.getWidth(), _img.getHeight());

        // Create a Bitmap of the appropriate format.
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(_img.getWidth(), _img.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

        // Set RGB pixels.
        result.setPixels(pixels, 0, result.getWidth(), 0, 0, result.getWidth(), result.getHeight());
        return result;
    }
```

Any ideas why I would get the runtime exception?!?!?!?

Comment: I am getting it when I call Mat m = Utils.bitmapToMap(imageBitMap); and I am pretty sure the underlying exception is out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reorganize my build path and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a SoftReference for ImageBitMap

```
SoftReference<BitMap> bimap = 
    new SoftRerenceBitmap<Bitmap>(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            mData, 0, mData.length);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I have even set the resolution of the camera to 960 X 430 and when the image is passed in I make a copy of it and delete the original.